# How to open .fodt files in LibreOffice by default?

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice

I'm using .fodt files because I need apply control version systems and git works better with .fodt files than .odt (.odt is binary, while .fodt is xml, more similar to plain text).

My problem is that every time I want to open it, I have to click with the right mouse button and select the "Open with..." menu. It would be interesting to set my preference in a permanent way.

Answer (score 4):

1. First Right Click
2. Then Go to properties
3. go to 'Open with' tab
4. Then choose the Libreoffice
5. click on set as default

done.